# Como inserir um arquivo HTML com o [innerHtml] e manter os atributos do Angular

Tags: html, angular, atributos

Em meu `Componente` eu recebo um HTML em forma de String e uso o [innerHtml] para inserir esse HTML na View do Component.

Component:

```
test(){
    alert('Teste :D');
}

html_string = '<input type="button" (click)="test()">';
```

View:

```
<div [innerHtml]="html_string"></div>
```

O problema que estou enfrentado é que no momento em que a pagina carrega, ela ignora o `(click)="teste()"`. No final ele acaba ficando no elemento, já outros que estão direto na View, no final somem do elemento.
E eu faço a validação com o `sanitizer`.

Answer (score 6):

#### Atualização 2

Caso não queira fazer o uso de biblioteca, você pode usar a classe [Compiler](https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler) ( Obs.: Não confundir com `$compile` do *AngularJS* )

Arquivo **app.component.ts**

```
import { Compiler, Component, Injector, NgModule, NgModuleRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('testando', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler, private _injector: Injector, private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) { }

  test() {
    alert('Teste :D');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const html_string = '<input type="button" (click)="test()" value={{btnValue}}>';
    const tmpCmp = Component({ template: html_string })(class { });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({ declarations: [tmpCmp] })(class { });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.btnValue = 'CLIQUE!';
        cmpRef.instance.test = this.test;
        this._container.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      })
  }
}
```

Arquivo **app.component.html**

```
<div #testando></div>
```

> Veja funcionando em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gklhvs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>
> O exemplo acima foi adaptado do artigo: [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e). ( Aqui está o que você precisa saber sobre componentes dinâmicos em Angular - Tradução livre. )

#### Atualização 1

Fazendo uma pesquisa no *Google*, encontrei a biblioteca [p3x-angular-compile](https://github.com/patrikx3/angular-compile).

Para utilizar, basta seguir os passos:

1. Importar a biblioteca no arquivo **app.module.ts**

   ```
   import { CompileModule} from 'p3x-angular-compile';
   ```
2. Configurar o modulo:

   ```
   @NgModule({
     imports: [ ... CompileModule],
     ...
   })
   ```
3. Código do template:

   ```
   <div *ngIf="true" 
     [p3x-compile]="html_string"
     [p3x-compile-ctx]="this" >
   </div>
   ```
4. Usar seu componente normalmente assim como esta na pergunta, com a exceção que os eventos devem ser precedidos por `context.`:

   ```
   html_string = `<input type="button" (click)="context.test('wmsouza')" value="CLIQUE AQUI!">`;

   test(nome) {
     alert(`Olá, ${nome}`);
   }
   ```

> Podes ver funcionando em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xadjdz)

---

Isso não é possível, pois a subclasse `DomSanitizer` simplesmente ignora, a solução seria utilizar o método `addEventListener` para registrar um evento no elemento.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  html_string;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private elRef: ElementRef, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  test = (nome) => {
    alert(`Olá, ${nome}`);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.html_string = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<input type="button" value="CLIQUE AQUI!">');
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', _ => { this.test('wmsouza') }, false);
  }
}
```

> Veja funcionando em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjy218?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Muito simples, utilize o `$compile`:

Coloque ele no seu `app.controller`:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $compile) {
```

...

Faça o **APPEND** do HTML assim:

```
var elementoHTML = document.getElementById("elemento");
angular.element(elementoHTML).html( $compile(response.data)($scope) );
```